# Error when using Pivot_wider function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

I am using `pivot_wider` function on the following sample data but look like I am missing something here as the output are producing `NA's` with not rightly placing data into its respective column. Any suggestion, please?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"), 
                        to = as.Date("2000-12-31"), 
                        by = "year"), 
                        Parameter = rep(c("A","B"), times = 10),
                        Value = runif(10,1,50)) %>% 
                        pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)
```

**Output**

```
> print(DF)
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   Date       A         B        
   <date>     <list>    <list>   
 1 1991-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
 2 1992-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
 3 1993-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
 4 1994-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
 5 1995-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
 6 1996-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
 7 1997-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
 8 1998-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
 9 1999-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
10 2000-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The error already tells you everything that is wrong: `Values from Value are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.`, and below, the warning message even gives you code to identify duplicates. If you read the warning and run the code, you can clearly see that, in the first row (date 1999-01-01), you have two values with parameter A, therefore they are duplicated and the frame can't be pivoted, as there would be two values under one row on the expected column "A", so `pivot_wider` does exactly that and saves two values in a single cell, inside a list.

Comment: I can see the error which is why I posted for suggestions :). **Output:** I want a `data.frame`  with three columns as `Date`, `A`, and `B` along with their values.

Comment: Sure. How do you intend to deal with duplicates? All of your `Date`/`Parameter` combinations have 2 rows each.

Comment: That is the output you have, what specifically is wrong with this output? As mentioned by @BastiánOleaHerrera the date and Parameter columns do not uniquely identify the values. For example, there are two values for 1991-01-01 with Parameter A. They are duplicated, but from your post it is not clear what you want. Do you want them in separate rows? Do you want them de-duplicated?

Comment: For instance, `"1991-01-01"` and `"A"` has two instances of `15.091298`. In this dataset, all values within a group of date/parameter are identical, which means we can do `... %>% distinct() %>% pivot_wider(...)` and it doesn't complain about list-columns. But then we get into the aesthetic issue that no date shares both A and B, so your resulting `DF` has as its first row `1 1991-01-01  15.1 NA` and its second row `2 1992-01-01  NA   39.6`.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to produce a starting frame _before_ `pivot_wider`, and then hand-craft how you expect that frame to come out after the pivot given the sample data itself. This will either clear it up for me (us) or clarify in your mind the challenge with this sample data. Either way, a win :-)

Comment: Ok probably i am creating the `data.frame` wrongly. I want a column with `date (1991-2000)`, then single values for `A` and `B` variables for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got an error in how you're generating your sample data. Apologies if this isn't what you're looking for, but here's how I think you can get your desired output:

**EDIT:** @s_pike provided the same solution below, about a minute before me, with an explanation of what we both changed. Sorry for omission and thanks to them for that- included now for clarity.

The problem is in your call to `rep()`. You're currently repeating A and B ten times, for a total of 20 values in the `Parameter` column. Because you're providing a vector of 10 dates, it will be recycled to match the length of `Parameter`. Because A and B are replicated one after the other, each date has the same `Parameter` value when `Date` is recycled: the cause of the duplication.

If instead you change the call to: `Parameter = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10))` each value in `Date` gets a `Parameter` of both A and B, so there are no duplications. See below:

```
> set.seed(123)
> DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"),
                            to = as.Date("2000-12-31"), 
                            by = "year"), 
                 Parameter = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),
                 Value = runif(10,1,50))

> DF
         Date Parameter     Value
1  1991-01-01         A 15.091298
2  1992-01-01         A 39.626952
3  1993-01-01         A 21.039869
4  1994-01-01         A 44.267853
5  1995-01-01         A 47.082897
6  1996-01-01         A  3.232268
7  1997-01-01         A 26.877169
8  1998-01-01         A 44.728533
9  1999-01-01         A 28.020316
10 2000-01-01         A 23.374122
11 1991-01-01         B 15.091298
12 1992-01-01         B 39.626952
13 1993-01-01         B 21.039869
14 1994-01-01         B 44.267853
15 1995-01-01         B 47.082897
16 1996-01-01         B  3.232268
17 1997-01-01         B 26.877169
18 1998-01-01         B 44.728533
19 1999-01-01         B 28.020316
20 2000-01-01         B 23.374122
```

This should do what you want and your `pivot_wider` should work now:

```
> DF %>% 
+     pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   Date           A     B
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1991-01-01 15.1  15.1 
 2 1992-01-01 39.6  39.6 
 3 1993-01-01 21.0  21.0 
 4 1994-01-01 44.3  44.3 
 5 1995-01-01 47.1  47.1 
 6 1996-01-01  3.23  3.23
 7 1997-01-01 26.9  26.9 
 8 1998-01-01 44.7  44.7 
 9 1999-01-01 28.0  28.0 
10 2000-01-01 23.4  23.4
```

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if you include the result of calling `pivot_wider` on the adjusted data frame you have created.

Comment: Quite right- I'll edit it now!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the repeat in the Parameter to `c(rep("A", times = 10), rep("B", times=10))`, assuming your intention is to have one `"A"` per year, and one `"B"` per year.

Compare your original:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"), 
                            to = as.Date("2000-12-31"), 
                            by = "year"), 
                 Parameter = rep(c("A","B"), times = 10),
                 Value = runif(10,1,50)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)

DF
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Date       A         B        
#>    <date>     <list>    <list>   
#>  1 1991-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
#>  2 1992-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
#>  3 1993-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
#>  4 1994-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
#>  5 1995-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
#>  6 1996-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
#>  7 1997-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
#>  8 1998-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
#>  9 1999-01-01 <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
#> 10 2000-01-01 <NULL>    <dbl [2]>
```

With:

```r
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"), 
                            to = as.Date("2000-12-31"), 
                            by = "year"), 
                 Parameter = c(rep("A", times = 10), rep("B", times=10)),
                 Value = runif(10,1,50)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value)

DF
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Date           A     B
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1991-01-01 47.9  47.9 
#>  2 1992-01-01 23.2  23.2 
#>  3 1993-01-01 34.2  34.2 
#>  4 1994-01-01 29.1  29.1 
#>  5 1995-01-01  6.04  6.04
#>  6 1996-01-01 45.1  45.1 
#>  7 1997-01-01 13.1  13.1 
#>  8 1998-01-01  3.06  3.06
#>  9 1999-01-01 17.1  17.1 
#> 10 2000-01-01 47.8  47.8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: not sure why this doesnt work here. `library(tidyhydat)
library(tidyverse)
G <- hy_annual_instant_peaks(station_number = "05ME006") %>% 
  filter(PEAK_CODE == "MAX") %>% 
  select(3,5,6) %>% 
  filter(between(year(Date),2002,2022)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = Value )`